# link Multiple Firebase project in single android / IOs app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm currently facing an issue related to integration of multiple Firebase projects into single Android/IOS application. Currently I'm trying this which is mentioned in google docs
[Firebase multiple account link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setProjectId("my-firebase-project")
        .setApplicationId("")
        .setApiKey("")
        // setDatabaseURL(...)
        // setStorageBucket(...)
        .build();
```

After adding all the details I'm facing an error which is **"Invalid credentials: access token invalid audience "**. Please guide me about this issue how I can overcome from this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This typically means that you're trying to sign in to one project with credentials from another project.

Comment: No I have checked the all details.Ok so is it possible that i can link single mobile app with multiple firebase project.
I don't want to upload new app to the playstore every time when there is new project requirement with same feature. Want some sort of dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create multiple firebase_option files for each firebase project and use them by

```
import 'firebase_options/firebase_options_dev.dart' as dev;
import 'firebase_options/firebase_options_prod.dart' as prod;
import 'firebase_options/firebase_options_stg.dart' as stg;

void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: Env.flavor == Flavor.prod
        ? prod.DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
        : Env.flavor == Flavor.stg
            ? stg.DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
            : dev.DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  run(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that but I am facing issue related to SHA-1,SHA keys.
In my case I have multiple deferent project with the same feature. So wanted to create single app for all. So whenever there is req for new project then i don't need to upload new app to playstore. The existing one will take care of it. Note: New project as in brand new firebase project